# Python: How to obtain overlapping calls column if I have two columns start_time and end_time with following conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time

I have calls data with two columns "start_time" and "end_time".
start_time means Timestamp of call started and
end_time means Timestamp of call ended.
I want to create a new column in Python df called "overlap" where overlap will have integer value of calls that have been overlapped in an hour corresponding to each row. start_time should be less than end_time for overlap column but only for that 1 hour timeslot

I have this df :

| start_time | end_time | timeslot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02-10-2020 23:47:10 | 02-10-2020 23:49:20 | 11pm to 12am |
| 02-10-2020 23:47:50 | 02-10-2020 23:53:10 | 11pm to 12am |
| 02-10-2020 23:48:23 | 02-10-2020 23:50:48 | 11pm to 12am |
| 02-10-2020 23:55:49 | 03-10-2020 00:03:27 | 11pm to 12am |
| 02-10-2020 23:58:22 | 02-10-2020 23:59:38 | 11am to 12am |
| 03-10-2020 00:02:17 | 03-10-2020 00:05:26 | 12am to 1am |
| 03-10-2020 00:07:45 | 03-10-2020 00:09:56 | 12am to 1am |

I want this df with new column "overlap" :

| start_time | end_time | timeslot | overlap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02-10-2020 23:47:10 | 02-10-2020 23:49:20 | 11pm to 12am | 3 |
| 02-10-2020 23:47:50 | 02-10-2020 23:53:10 | 11pm to 12am | 2 |
| 02-10-2020 23:48:23 | 02-10-2020 23:50:48 | 11pm to 12am | 1 |
| 02-10-2020 23:55:49 | 03-10-2020 00:03:27 | 11pm to 12am | 2 |
| 02-10-2020 23:58:22 | 02-10-2020 23:59:38 | 11am to 12am | 1 |
| 03-10-2020 00:02:17 | 03-10-2020 00:05:26 | 12am to 1am | 2 |
| 03-10-2020 00:04:45 | 03-10-2020 00:09:56 | 12am to 1am | 1 |

Notice that for the 4th row, overlap value is 2 and not 3 because timeslot has been changed, so need to calculate "overlap" for the current timeslots only. I have both time columns in datetime64[ns] format. How do I create "overlap" column in Python? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: the value of (4th line, 'timeslot') should be '11pm to 1am' not '11pm to 12am'

Comment: Thanks but that is kept on purpose. timeslot is based on start_time column and for only 1 hour

Comment: If you were doing this manually how would you decide whether something represents an overlap, how would you count up how many total overlaps there were, and how would you decide which of the overlaps belong in the same row of the output table?